# Swift 3: Meaning of parenthesis around unwrapped optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I have noticed when I code in Swift I routinely get an auto correct from the compiler when I use optionals and I am trying to understand the meaning behind this. When I have a variable that is optional and I try to use without unwrapping it, I often get a `(?)!` autocorrection from Xcode.

In my code I have an optional property that will be the data source collection for my `UITableView`:

`var procedures: [Procedure]?`

First I will try to use it like so:

[image]

The compiler is telling me that I need to use the `?` syntax suffix for my `self.procedures`.

[image]

So I click on the little red circle and have it autocorrect for me like so:

[image]

But now the compiler is still complaining. About what you ask? Well, it apparently wants `self.procedures?.[indexPath.row]` to be enclosed in parenthesis with the `!` bang operator at the end...

So I click the little red circle again and have it auto correct like so:

[image]

Now the compiler is happy, but I am not. Why am I not happy you ask? Because I do not understand what the `()` parenthesis are doing here.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: you can safely remove the parenthesis in most of the cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you can see, you are declaring your procedures as an optional

```
var procedures: [Procedure]?
```

then you are trying to pass it to a function that will accept Procedure

```
cell.configureWithProcedure(procedure: Procedure)
```

Then you are trying to access your procedure with index like this

```
self.procedures[indexpath.row]
```

That will result an error because `self.procedures` is an optional, so you need to unwrap it, then you try to add ?

```
self.procedures?[indexpath.row]
```

This will solve the problem, but the result of it won't be a normal `Procedure` but an Optional Procedure -> `Procedure?`.
So XCode give you a hint to unwrap it because your `configureWithProcedure` ask for `Procedure` not `Procedure?` in one line that will be writen like this

```
(self.procedures?[indexPath.row])!
```

This operation will result unwrapped Procedure, but I don't recommend you to use the `!` operator because it's dangerous, so I recommend you to do like this

```
if let procedure = self.procedures?[indexPath.row] {
    cell.configureWithProcedure(procedure: procedure)
}
```

EDIT :

in your case you can return an empty cell if procedure isn't exist

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    dynamic class func emptyCell() -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell
    }
}
```

and write it like this

```
if let procedure = self.procedures?[indexPath.row] {
    cell.configureWithProcedure(procedure: procedure)
} else {
    return UITableView.emptyCell()
}
```

or even better use guard

```
guard let procedure = self.procedures?[indexPath.row] else {
   return UITableView.emptyCell()
}
cell.configureWithProcedure(procedure: procedure)
```

Hope my answer can help you!

Comment: So you are saying the `()` is a "hint"? I understand that if I unwrap it with an `if let` then it is the safer way to do this without running into the problem that I had, BUT... then what if I do not have any procedures? Then in the `else` after the `if let` I need to say `return nil`... but... Swift doesn't like us doing that. So I am left between a rock and a hard place because Swift is so difficult to satisfy.

Comment: @BrandonA Yes, because you can't unwrap it like this 'self.procedures?[indexPath.row]!' you need to wrap it with braces '()' like I write above. For your problem with the else, you have a lot of choice, you can choice to just return an empty cell like I wrote above (check edited answer) or you could change your configureWithProcedure to accept an optional and configure it to show default value or maybe empty cell if the procedure is not exist.

Comment: If you are sure that Procedure object in procedures array will never be nil then you can also declare it as var procedures: [Procedure!]?. So it will not ask for unwrapping the object in that array with ().